# getting user input from mouse click in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering if it's possible to get user input from whatever the user clicks on (e.g a link) and storing it as a string value? For example, I have a link "hello" and when the user clicks on that link, the string "hello" will be stored in a variable to be used for filtering later.

In depth example

A table generated from a database using sqlalchemy

```
|School_Name|Location      
==========================
|Jackson    |San Francisco 
|Sample     |San Jose      
|Sample B   |New York
```

Let's say I want to change the school_name values into links so when the user clicks on one of them, it will send them to a filtered page, the string will be used as a variable to filter only listing items with that value.

I've spent the entire day yesterday on google trying to find references for this but can't... I'm rather new at python and programming so maybe there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Python, by itself, does not interact with a graphical user environment, so it has no concept of mouse clicks.  It sounds to me like what you want is a GUI library for Python, of which [there are many](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming).